# Create indexes in solr on top of HBase

Tags: solr, hbase, cloudera, inverted-index

Is there anyway in which I can create indexes in Solr to perform full-text search from HBase  for Near Real Time.

I didn't wanted to store the whole text in my solr indexes. Made `"stored=false"`

Note: - Keeping in mind, I am working on large datasets and want to do Near Real Time search. WE are talking TB/PB of data.

### UPDATED

Cloudera Distribution : 5.4.x is used with Cloudera Search components.

Solr : 4.10.x

HBase : 1.0.x

Indexer Service : Lily HBase Indexer with cloudera morphlines

Is there any other NRT Indexer services or frameworks which can be used instead of Lily on **Cloudera**. Just a thought.

Comment: this question has deep insight towards hbase solr integration. Its useful for others as well. Hence, I upvoted it

Comment: Also adding for the multivalued field updations in Solr using Lily and Morphline http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420800/how-to-insert-multivalued-field-in-solr-using-lily-morphline

Comment: If searching in non-rowkey column of hbase is the goal, will secondary indixes in hbase serve your purpose? Have you evaluated it?

Comment: @Mahesha999 : The Solution marked here is the accepted answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cloudera :**
please check [this article](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/53/nrt-near-real-time-indexing-cloudera-search-lily-hbase-indexer-morphline-apache-solr-lucene-tika-zooKeeper) and [Hbase-Solr using Cloudera-search](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hbase-solr-real-time-indexing-search-deepak) which describes how to achieve that. see below screen shot as described by those articles.
[image: Bird view of hbase solr integration]
[**Have a look at known issues with Cloudera Search**](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_search_ki.html)

Yes you can consider Morphlines. they  can be used for near real-time applications as well as batch processing applications.

I don't know much about hortonworks platform and how this can be achieved.