# REST API for processing data stored in hbase

Tags: rest, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, bigdata

I have a lot of records in hbase store (millions) like this

```
key = user_id:service_id:usage_timestamp value = some_int
```

That means an user used some *service_id* for *some_int* at *usage_timestamp*.

And now I wanted to provide some rest api for aggregating that data. For example "find sum of all values for requested user" or "find max of them" and so on. So I'm looking for the best practise. Simple java application doesn't met my performance expectations.

My current approach - aggregates data via apache spark application, looks good enough but there are some issues to use it with java rest api so far as spark doesn't support request-response model (also I have took a view into spark-job-server, seems raw and unstable)

Thanks,

Any ideas?

Comment: Check My answer. Solr way should be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just want to wait few days more for possible answers. Don't worry, I will accept some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would offer Hbase + Solr if you are using Cloudera (i.e Cloudera search)*

[Solrj api](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)  for aggregating data(instead of spark), to interact with rest services

**Solr Solution (in cloudera its Cloudera search) :**

1. Create a collection (similar to hbase table) in solr.
2. ***Indexing :*** Use NRT lily indexer or custom mapreduce solr document creator to load data as solr documents.

   If you don't like NRT lily indexer you can use spark or mapreduce job with Solrj to do the indexing For ex: [Spark Solr :
   Tools for reading data from Solr as a Spark RDD and indexing objects from Spark into Solr using SolrJ.](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr)
3. ***Data Retrieval*** : Use Solrj to get the solr docs from your web service call.
   In Solrj,

   - There is [FieldStatInfo](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.FieldStatsInfo) through which Sum,Max etc.... can be achieved
   - There are Facets and Facetpivots to group data
   - Pagination is supported for rest API calls

   ***you can integrate solr results with Jersey or some other web service as we have already implemented this way.***

   ```
   /**This method returns the records for the specified rows from Solr Server which you can integrate with any rest api like jersey etc...
        */
       public SolrDocumentList getData(int start, int pageSize, SolrQuery query) throws SolrServerException {
           query.setStart(start); // start of your page
           query.setRows(pageSize);// number of rows per page
           LOG.info(ClientUtils.toQueryString(query, true));
           final QueryResponse queryResponse = solrCore.query(query, METHOD.POST); // post is important if you are querying huge result set Note : Get will fail for huge results
           final SolrDocumentList solrDocumentList = queryResponse.getResults();
           if (isResultEmpty(solrDocumentList)) { // check if list is empty
               LOG.info("hmm.. No records found for this query");
           }
           return solrDocumentList;
   ```

   }

Also look at

1. my answer in "[Create indexes in solr on top of HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318176/create-indexes-in-solr-on-top-of-hbase)"
2. https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/7892/spark-dataframe-to-solr-cloud-runs-on-sandbox-232.html

***Note : I think same can be achieved with elastic search as well. But out of my experience , Im confident with Solr + solrj***

Comment: @JustinKestelyn: Since you belong to cloudera Im asking this question :)  What about cloudera search ? Is it opt for the above question. What option cloudera prefers for hbase + Spark kind of processing?

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

1. [Livy REST Server](https://github.com/cloudera/livy) - new REST Server, created by Cloudera. You can submit Spark jobs in REST way. It is new and developed by Cloudera, one of the biggest Big Data / Spark company, so it's very possible that it will be developed in future, not abandoned
2. You can run Spark Thrift Server and connect just like to normal database via JDBC. [Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server) you've got documentation. Workflow: read data, preprocess and then share by Spark Thrift Server

If you want to isolate third-party apps from Spark you can create simple application that will have user-friendly endpoint and will translate query received by endpoint to Livy-Spark jobs or SQL that will be used with Spark Thrift Server

Comment: Just FYI: Livy is not in fact "supported" by Cloudera for production use. But we do encourage its use for test & dev.

Comment: @JustinKestelyn You are right, I mean that Livy is developed by Cloudera, which means it will be developed in future, not abandoned :)

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to make that clear (the word "support" has specific meaning to paying customers).

Comment: @JustinKestelyn Thanks :) I've updated answer to not confuse anyone